# Как перевернуть ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Как перевернуть ListView? Чтобы новые элементы, которые добавляются динамически, добавлялись вверх списка. Вообщем, также как это сделано в Instagram, VK и т.д.

Comment: А язык и платформу нам вы предлагаете угадать?

Comment: @VladD Я голосую за Titanium и JavaScript, там есть ListView :)

Comment: )))) Извините, я про андроид )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Android:

```
ArrayList elements = new ArrayList();
elements.add(0, newObject);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Для скролла на ноль используйте listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуй. Т.к. `ListView` содержит в себе коллекцию того, чего ему надо отображать, то когда ты пытаешься добавить новый элемент, вставляй его в коллекцию на нулевое место.

Пример java : `listView.getItems().add(0, newElement)`